# How to call an API inside an Azure ILB ASE from a webapp within the same ASE

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, internal-load-balancer, vnet

I have an Azure ILB ASE deployed, and a webapp deployed inside it at (for example) `https://myapp.my-internal domain`. I have an Application Gateway configured, mapping an external domain name to that app via the ILB, and this works well - I can connect to the webapp from the internet via the Application Gateway, as expected.

My webapp needs to talk to an API deployed to the same ILB ASE, at (for example) `https://myapi.my-internal-domain` - but when it tries to make this connection, it fails, being unable to resolve the internal domain name:

[image]

How can I configure my web app so it can find an api app within the same ILB ASE?

Comment: Have you tried adding WEBSITE_DNS_SERVER and WEBSITE_DNS_ALT_SERVER to your web app's AppSettings?  Take a look at this: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/09/11/use-appkey-to-change-webapps-default-dns-settings-since-ase-app-services-dont-inherit-vnets-dns-settings/

Comment: Success! In combination with an Azure DNS zone pointing the address of each app to the ILB private IP, and using the IP of the DNS servers (as opposed to *.azure-dns.com &c), that works.

Many thanks - that dug me out of a seemingly impossible hole. If you can write up an answer, will accept - otherwise I will in a few days to document.

Answer (score 3):

I will summarize the comment to let others who have same question get answer quickly.

To to manually overwrite the MS default DNS settings and use the internal DNS server for web app service, the solution is to add `Website_DNS_Server= primary DNS server IP` and  `Website_DNS_ALT_Server=secondary DNS server IP`” under the App Settings in webapp.

[image]

Don't forget to point the address of each app to the ILB private IP in Azure DNS zone.
For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/09/11/use-appkey-to-change-webapps-default-dns-settings-since-ase-app-services-dont-inherit-vnets-dns-settings/).